# Loop selecting one item per list in nested list

Tags: python, indexing, nested-lists

```
list = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

I would like to have a loop that randomly selects only ONE item from the indexes of the list for all 3 of them. So the loop would start and pick 3, then picks 7 and then picks 9, for example. And then the loop stops, doesn't continue on picking items again. I only want 3 repetitions
I have managed to do this
(with:

```
for i in list:
item = list[0].pop((random.choice(list)[0])))
```

but it doesn't do it only once, but it goes through all of the items (choosing the first one) of the first index, then moves to the second one and so on.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us expected output?

Comment: Also, best not to name variables using python keywords (i.e. `list`, in this case)...

Comment: The expected output would be, for example:
# [3, 7, 9]
And then code continues by doing some other function for these numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be indexing the list on `0` in each iteration, which will only give you random values from the first inner list. Use `random.choice` iterating over the list, or use `map`:

```
list(map(random.choice, my_list))
# [3, 8, 11]
```

Equivalently:

```
[random.choice(i) for i in my_list]
```

---

Based on the comments, if you want to remove the item you've randomly selected from the list, use instead:

```
[i.pop(random.randint(0,len(i))) for i in my_list]
# [4, 6, 9]
print(my_list)
# [[1, 2, 3], [5, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Yes indeed you are right. So the random.choice works great. But then in the loop I still need to use to pop function to remove the item used. So I create the new list with random.choice and then:
for i in my_list:
item = my_list.pop

But then it skips 2 trials, it doesn't iterate over the list for all numbers of the list

Comment: Indeed it worked like this but it doesn't always work (which is weird).Sometimes I get the error, 
`IndexError: pop index out of range`
even though the list is still the same

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

````
print("before random sample",pos)
pos = random.sample(pos, len(pos))
print("after random sample", pos)
test = [i.pop(random.randint(0,len(i))) for i in pos]```

This is the output:

#before random sample [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
#after random sample [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
#.......
#test = [i.pop(random.randint(0,len(i))) for i in pos]
#IndexError: pop index out of range
````